# "'glib.h' file not found" when I make source project in mac OS

Tags: makefile, thrift, configure, glib, autoconf

I created MakeFile using Autoconf. When I run "make" in my source project, errors like below occur. But glib is installed. Does anyone have a solution to this problem? I'm using thrift library in my project.

```
/usr/local/include/thrift/c_glib/thrift.h:27:10: fatal error: 'glib.h' file not found
#include <glib.h>
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I tried this command but it didn't fix this problem.

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Comment: as I understand it, the error is complaining that it can't find glib.h.  This means you need to include in your compile command the directory where that file is.  i.e. ```-I <path to glib.h>```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm using "configure.ac" file. Which file and how should I put <path to glib.h>?

Comment: unfortunately, my understanding of macOS is limited at best, sorry. I'm kinda surprised that it doesn't detect glib.h via configure..